# Joule-Thomson Expression for dT

Tags: thermodynamics

In H. Callen's "Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics" in the chapter about the Joule-Thomson process, they say:

> "If the change in pressure in a throttling process is sufficiently
>   small we can employ the usual differential analysis"
>   $$
>  dT = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)\bigg|_{H, N_1, N_2, ...}dP
> $$

How does one get to this equation for $dT$?

I can't find any references to this (while skimming through other chapters) and I'm not entirely sure what this relationship is called. As far as I know, you can write $T(S,P,N)$ as an equation of state using the enthalpy equation, but writing $dT$ gives

$$
dT = \frac{\partial T}{\partial S}\bigg|_{P,N}dS + \frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\bigg|_{S,N}dP + \frac{\partial T}{\partial N}\bigg|_{S,P}dN
$$

I can understand if $dN = 0$, but is it possible to also have $dS = 0$ for this process?

One can show $dH = 0$, and since it appears to be held constant, I figure this is the right track, but this is not in the equation above.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: eliminate $S$ and replace it with $H$, then $T=T(H,P,N)$

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just not sure how one would go about doing that. $H \ne S$ right? Can you just replace it, or is it an application of the chain rule?

Comment: since $dH=TdS+Vdp+\mu dN$ you can immediately turn this around for $dS$ that can be integrated (solved) for $S=S(H,V,N)$, and if you already have a function $T=T_1(S,V,N)$ then you can have an *other*  function $T=T_2(H,V,N)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation to start with is $$dH=C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$which is derived directly from $$dH=TdS+VdP$$